# iOS: Record audio in other format than caf

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-recording, caf

I am working on audio recording. I am able to record my audio in caf (Core audio format). Now I want to record sound in `.mp3` or `.amr`.

I tried a lot of google but didn't found anything. I am not sure if my steps following work:

> Write that Audio with `.caf` extention to document dir
>
> Read data from that file
>
> write the file again with `.mp3 or .amr extention`

I have 100% doubt that this will not going to work as this will just re save file with some other extension. This won't change audio codec.

I thought that for converting any format whether it is audio or video we need to change its codecs and data sequence.

Please also suggest me any player which don't play `.caf` files not anything else. So I can make sure that my files are converted successfully.

**UPDATE** Please also let me know that the way I am re-writing data with different extension is correct in the way I am needed?

Comment: u can't record in mp3 or amr Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1615/_index.html) link

Comment: u will need to convert .caf file into mp3 or amr

Comment: using the way I explained will my file get converted?

Comment: u can convert into m4a, aac , amr thats what i know

Comment: and How can I convert it? do you have any tutorial or link which guide me to convert it to amr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/) example.
The `MP3` format is however not available due to patents, maybe you can use [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

From the Document [The Basics: Audio Codecs, Supported Audio Formats, and Audio Sessions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6)

Comment: Link is dead. This is why SO frowns upon link-only answers. Copy the relevant information into the answer, don't just supply a link.